# Firebase Google Authentication Constructor undefined Error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, firebase

Soo. I have been trying to implement Firebase google auth in my project, Unfortunately I ran into the following error on the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')
    at _assertInstanceOf (assert.ts:101:1)
    at signInWithPopup (popup.ts:86:1)
    at signInWithGoogle (App.js:52:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
```

The Code goes as followed

```
import React from "react";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth , GoogleAuthProvider , signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth"

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app);

function Home() {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header>Welcome to PixShare</header>
            <h1>
                Home
                <section>
                    {user ? <Home /> : <SignIn />}
                </section>
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
}

const SignIn = () => {
    const signInWithGoogle = () => {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        signInWithPopup(provider)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={ signInWithGoogle }>
            Sign In With Google
        </button>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Can someone help me with what went wrong?
The package.json file is as shown below

```
{
  "name": "pixshare",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong? Could really use some help

Answer (score 1):

The `signInWithPopup()` function takes an `Auth` instance as the first argument.
So the `signInWithPopup(provider)` function should be `signInWithPopup(auth, provider)`